# Showing that the sgn of the first entry of the matrix satisfies multiplicative property when the matrix belongs to a group

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry for the vague title, but I can't think of anything else.

I need help showing part (c) of this question.[image]

I have shown part (a) and (b) already, but I have no idea how to approach (c). I can show that if $A$ is in $O(1,3)$, then $A^{-1}$ is too. I can also show that if $A \in O(1,3)$ and $B \in O(1,3)$, then so is $AB \in O(1,3)$, but I have no idea how to prove the actual statement. Any hints?